# Downloading Gmail associated with a label

Tags: gmail, google-takeout

I just finished a project and would like to download (to my local hard drive) copies of all of my emails in Gmail associated with this project. These emails have already been applied with a common label that uniquely identifies them. What are some ways to do this please?

I'm comfortable with "everyday" software, can look things up, follow instructions, etc. but not advanced enough to write my own scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is with Thunderbird, another way is with the Google interface, as follows:

When you're in your gmail account, there is a profile icon in the top right corner.  It might look like a blue person, or it might have a custom photograph you uploaded.  Click on it, and choose "Account."  Now click on "Download data" under "Account tools."  Click on "Select none," and then click to the right of Mail in the alphabetized list.  There is a little arrow just to the left of the green checkmark.  Click on that.  Choose "Select labels", choose appropriately, and at the bottom of the page, click "Next."  Choose the appropriate delivery method (Drive or email), and click on "Create archive."  I tried this out and it hadn't finished yet after half an hour, for a label with a dozen short messages.  While it was working, a message was displayed saying "Please note that mail archives may take a long time (hours or possibly days) to create."

If it gives you trouble -- thunderbird works great.  Your gmail label will show up as a folder in thunderbird.  And that will correspond to a folder in your thunderbird profile.

Comment: By the way, my test eventually completed, but I'm not planning on doing it that way myself in future -- it took all night.  I'm sticking with thunderbird!

Comment: The gmail download has moved to My Account > Personal Info & Privacy > Control your content

Comment: The gmail download has moved again. axxis's described action takes you to a sales pitch for more storage as a subscription service.